# Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Bom pessoal, depois de uma longa pesquisa no google, não encontrei nada semelhante ao meu problema, então pensei em relatar aqui.

Ontem um sistema que estou construindo começou exibir este problema "Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento". O servidor que estou usando é o XAMPP e o navegador é o Chrome.

Na hora que o problema aconteceu, eu estava escrevendo um sistema de paginação e tinha logado uma conta no login pra fazer uns testes básicos. Agora toda vez que tento abrir a pagina principal onde o usuário digita a senha pra logar aparece "Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento".

Tentei alguns diagnóstico sugerido pelo Chrome, mas nada funcionou. Eu também apaguei todo código até o momento que sei que o sistema estava funcionando, mas também não funcionou.

Alguém já passou por isso antes?

Aqui esta um pedaço do código

Conexão com o banco de dados conexao_sessao.php

```
//Seleciona o banco de dados

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "sessao";

// as variáveis email e senha recebem os dados digitados na página anterior
$email = (isset($_POST['Email'])) ? $_POST['Email'] : $_SESSION['Email']; // se n tiver post, utiliza sessao
$senha = (isset($_POST['Senha'])) ? $_POST['Senha'] : $_SESSION['Senha']; // se n tiver post, utiliza sessao

//Conexão mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Erro na conexão do banco de dados.");

//Conexao com banco de dados
$selecionabd = mysql_select_db($database,$conexao) or die ("Banco de dados inexistente.");

//Comando SQL de verificação de autenticação
$tabela = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email = '$email' AND Senha = '$senha'";

$resultado = mysql_query($tabela,$conexao) or die ("Erro na seleção da tabela.");

//Caso consiga logar cria a sessão 
if (mysql_num_rows ($resultado)) {

    $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['Senha'] = $senha;
}

//Caso contrário redireciona para a página de autenticação
else{                                                             
    //Destrói
    session_destroy();

    //Limpa
    unset ($_SESSION['Email']);
    unset ($_SESSION['Senha']); 

    //Redireciona para a página de autenticação
    header('location:principal.php');

}
```

---

Pagina principa, principal.php

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Pagina Pricipal</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "conexao_sessao.php"; ?>

<form method="post" action="profile.php" >
<label>E-mail: </label>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /><br />
<label>Senha:</label>
<input type="password" name="Senha" id="Senha" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Login"  />
<a href= "novo_usuario.php">Cadastre-se</a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Pagina que abre depois que o usuario logar, profile.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include "conexao_sessao.php";

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {

    //Destrói
    session_destroy();

    //Limpa
    unset ($_SESSION['login']);
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']); 

    //Redireciona para a página de autenticação
    header('location:principal.php');

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<body>
<head>
    <meta charsert="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Sistema de Comentários</title>
</head>
<a href="principal.php?logout=1">Sair</a>
</br>
</br>
<a href="responda.php">Clique aqui para responder perguntas!</a>
</br>
<a href="EditandoPerfil/editar_perfil.php">Editar Perfil!</a>
<hr>
</br>
<h3>Perguntas Respondidas</h3>
</br>
<hr>

<?php include("RespondaGlobal/mostrar.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá @evandro-lauro, Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Se possível, poste partes do seu código para podermos melhor lhe auxiliar. Você pode começar dando uma olhada nos locais onde faz redirecionamentos para verificar se não existe algum bug que pode estar fazendo isso (exemplo, uma pagina que redireciona para outra em loop infinito devido a uma falha de validação)

Comment: Posta o código que verifica o login. A parte que checa a sessão do login. É 90%  de certeza que o loop está nesse trecho.

Comment: bingo.. é isso.. conexao_sessao.php não deveria ser incluido dessa forma.

Comment: @DanielOmine porquê?

Comment: Tenta trocar todos os include por **include_once**

Answer (score 1):

O `loop de redirecionamento` é criado quando um `Location` de uma página gera um novo `Location`.

Por exemplo:

```
index.php [Location: login.php] ->
login.php [Location: index.php] ->
index.php [Location: login.php] ->
login.php [Location: index.php] ->
Fim, loop de redirecionamento
```

Isso não necessariamente exige duas páginas, podendo ser a mesma, como no seu caso.

**Cade o problema:**

```
//Caso contrário redireciona para a página de autenticação
else{                                                             
    //Destrói
    session_destroy();

    //Limpa
    unset ($_SESSION['Email']);
    unset ($_SESSION['Senha']); 

    //Redireciona para a página de autenticação
    header('location:principal.php');

}
```

Este trecho possui o problema.
O `header('location:principal.php');` irá sempre ser acionado quando o usuário carrega a página, sem mesmo ter digitado/enviado um e-mail ou senha.

Isso é, sempre que entra na página é enviado um `Location: principal.php`, quando carrega é enviado um novo `Location: principal.php`, gerando um loop.

**Como corrigir:**

Comece do começo, verificando a necessidade de rodar o script:

```
<?php
    //Seleciona o banco de dados

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "sessao";

    ## MODIFICAÇÃO

    if(isset($_POST['Email']) or isset($_SESSION['Email'])){

    ## FIM DA MODIFICAÇÃO

    // as variáveis email e senha recebem os dados digitados na página anterior
    $email = (isset($_POST['Email'])) ? $_POST['Email'] : $_SESSION['Email']; // se n tiver post, utiliza sessao
    $senha = (isset($_POST['Senha'])) ? $_POST['Senha'] : $_SESSION['Senha']; // se n tiver post, utiliza sessao

    //Conexão mysql
    $conexao = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Erro na conexão do banco de dados.");

    //Conexao com banco de dados
    $selecionabd = mysql_select_db($database,$conexao) or die ("Banco de dados inexistente.");

    //Comando SQL de verificação de autenticação
    $tabela = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email = '$email' AND Senha = '$senha'";

    $resultado = mysql_query($tabela,$conexao) or die ("Erro na seleção da tabela.");

    //Caso consiga logar cria a sessão 
    if (mysql_num_rows ($resultado)) {

        $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['Senha'] = $senha;
    }

    //Caso contrário redireciona para a página de autenticação
    else{                                                             
        //Destrói
        session_destroy();

        //Limpa
        unset ($_SESSION['Email']);
        unset ($_SESSION['Senha']); 

        //Redireciona para a página de autenticação
        header('location:principal.php');

    }

    ## MODIFICAÇÃO

    }

    ## FIM DA MODIFICAÇÃO
?>
```

Um simples `if(isset($_POST) or isset($_SESSION)){` irá validar se existe uma sessão ou se existe um POST, isso é, se alguém digitou/enviou alguma coisa.

Isso irá retornar false e false, se um usuário estiver desconectado e não tiver enviado nada, assim também irá cair da condição mencionada anteriormente, não fazendo um novo redirecionamento, criando um loop.

Comment: Rodei o código editado por vc, mas o erro persiste. 

Valeu pela atenção.

Comment: Limpe o cache e cookies, ou utilize janela anonima para  ver se o problema persiste.

Comment: Já tentei isso. Poxa vida. O código tava rodando de boa.

Comment: Caso remova (todos) os `header('location:principal.php');` o problema ainda persiste? Se sim, pode ser um cache, acesse usando outro dispositivo (seu celular). Aparentemente não há nada para redirecionar, uma vez que não há nenhum envio, exceto se existir o SESSION, mas isso somente seria feito caso já tenha se conectado.

Comment: Não daria para eu acessar com outro dispositivo, porque o sistema ta no localhost. Bom fiz oque você mandou, exclui todos os header('location:principal.php'); até o da pagina conexao_sessao.php. Estou conseguindo acessar a pagina principal.php, logar na pagina profile.php e voltar para pagina principal.php pelo botão sair. Mas esta retornando as seguintes noticias:

Comment: >Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\conexao_sessao.php on line 16

>Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\conexao_sessao.php on line 17

>Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\conexao_sessao.php on line 40

>Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\conexao_sessao.php on line 43

>Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\conexao_sessao.php on line 44

Comment: Se eu coloco o header('location:principal.php'); na pagina conexao_sessao.php o erro de redirecionamento volta acontecer.

Comment: Bom, lembra do código da pagina conexao_sessao.php q vc fez eu substituir? Então rodei ele agora sem o  header('location:principal.php');

Aparentemente ta rodando perfeitamente.

Comment: O problema neste caso é que não irá redirecionar caso o usuário entre em `profile.php` sem ter feito o login. Experimente dar um `session_start()` no topo do arquivo, antes de `//Seleciona o banco de dados`, para que o $_SESSION funcione.

Comment: Descobri o exato momento que o problema acontece, é quando digito um email que não esta presente no banco de dados.

Comment: Tente alterar o `if(mysql_num_rows ($resultado))` para `if(mysql_num_rows ($resultado) >= 1)`, dessa forma se não resultar em nada não irá salvar um SESSION.

Comment: Arrumou. Mas dentro do sistema aconteceu uns erros tipo Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\MostrarGeneros\primeiraguerramundial.php on line 5